# NetBeans: как отключить заставку при запуске?

Tags: netbeans

Подскажите как отключить заставку, которая отображается при запуске NetBeans:

[image: Заставка NetBeans]

**ОС**: Ubuntu.

Comment: Отвернуться от экрана, закрыть глаза минут на 10.

Comment: Вы можете отключить, но задержка при запуске останется, Пока загружаются osgi модули.

Comment: @AkaInq, это понятно; просто когда показывается заставка, то у меня она располагается поверх всех окон (только терминал может всплыть над ней) и, видимо из-за этого, не работает клавиатура, так как фокус находится «на заставке»; только в терминале работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для отключения заставки при запуске Netbeans необходимо в конфигурационном файле, который расположен в папке редактора (в Ubuntu *по умолчанию* это `/usr/local/netbeans-8.1`) по пути `etc/netbeans.conf`, добавить к параметру `netbeans_default_options` опцию `--nosplash`; то есть полностью строка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.region=US --nosplash"
```